# Associate return value to a function parameter (CALL BY REFERENCE)

Tags: php

I am wondering about returning value to a parameter instead of using `=`

example of "normal" way how to get return value

```
function dummy() {
    return false;
}

$var = dummy();
```

But I am looking for a method how to associate return value without using `=`, like [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
function dummy($return_here) {
    return false;
}
dummy($var2);
var_dump($var2); //would output BOOLEAN(FALSE)
```

I am sure it has something to do with pointers but in `preg_match_all()` I never send any pointer to variable or am I mistaken?

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $data, $matches); // I am sending $matches here not &$matches
```

//I didn't know what to search for well it is simple `CALL BY REFERENCE`

Comment: ok, right away in doc I linked to, there is a function declaration like `int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )` The most important part is `&$matches`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is CALL BY REFERENCE:

```
function dummy(&$var) { //main difference is in this line
    $var = false;
}

dummy($var);
```

Comment: For more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 2):

Use references

i.e.

```
function dummy(&$return_here) {
    $return_here = false;
}
dummy($var2);
var_dump($var2);
```

Comment: Yes, got it myself I didn't read well the doc, answer was right there.

Comment: @Kyslik - Well accept the answer

Comment: how greedy you are, you should know by now it is impossible to accept answer before 10 minutes mark, @second comment, exactly what I was going to do ;)